# Shiny inputs: how do you make a multiline label?

Tags: r, shiny

Sometimes I would like to have long labels for my shiny `xxxInput` options. Take for example this radio button which chooses a time direction to subset a dataset of planes arriving at an airport. I would like to include a mini explanation of the choices in the label. However, naively including `\n` does not seem to work to make the label multiline.

```
radioButtons(inputId = "dir",
                          label = "Choose direction to look for plane arrivals: 
                              \nafter selected time, 
                              \nbefore selected time, 
                              \nor both.",
                          choices = c("after", "before", "both"),
                          inline = T,
                          selected = "both")
```

Comment: One option is to invoke it as HTML, i.e. `label = HTML("Choose direction to look for plane arrivals: 
                              <br />after selected time, 
                              <br />before selected time, 
                              <br />or both.")`

Comment: well ,that works perfectly.